# get unread message count for each conversation for a given user

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named "messages"

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5deb2ac39dd53e1dc8aabcdd"), 
  "conversation" : "5dda0890d4716849ccb593c6", 
  "message" : "hi", 
  "readBy" : [ ObjectId("5dc4ee8936070ba1a51e43ab"),...], 
  "deliveredTo" : [ObjectId("5dc4ee8936070ba1a51e43ab")...], 
  "sender"   : ObjectId("5dc4ee8a36070ba1a51e43b2"), 
  }
```

I want to get the unread message count for a  given conversation list ,

expected output

```
{
  conversationId1 : unread msg count,
  conversationId2 : unread msg count,
}
```

Pleas help.. I new with mongodb

My try:

```
db.messages.aggregate([{
    "$match":{
    "conversation": 
        {
            "$in": ["5dda0890d4716849ccb593c6","5ddbb2d23e77ad5b04801327"]
        },
    "readBy": 
        {
            "$ne": ObjectId("5dc4ee8a36070ba1a51e43b2")
        }
   },
   "$group": {
        "_id": "$conversation"
     "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
}])
```

Comment: Please precise : you want to retrieve message unread (readBy null or empty) or unread by a particular user (readBy does not contain user _id)?

Comment: unread by a particular user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate `$match` and `$group` into two pipeline. Something like this will work:

```
db.messages.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "conversation": {
        "$in": [
          "5dda0890d4716849ccb593c6",
          "5ddbb2d23e77ad5b04801327"
        ]
      },
      "readBy": {
        "$ne": ObjectId("5dc4ee8a36070ba1a51e43b2")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$conversation",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is the pipeline you are looking for:

```java
db.messages.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "conversation": {
                "$in": [
                    "5dda0890d4716849ccb593c6",
                    "5ddbb2d23e77ad5b04801327"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "conversation": "$conversation",
            "unreadCount": {
                "$subtract": [
                    {
                        "$size": "$deliveredTo"
                    },
                    {
                        "$size": "$readBy"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "_id": 0
        }
    }
])
```

here's the c# code that generated the above:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class message : Entity
    {
        public string conversation { get; set; }
        public string[] deliveredTo { get; set; }
        public string[] readBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new[] {
                new message {
                    conversation = "first-convo",
                    deliveredTo = new[] {"aaaa","bbbb"},
                    readBy = new[] {"bbbb"}
                },
                new message {
                    conversation = "second-convo",
                    deliveredTo = new[] {"cccc","dddd","eeee"},
                    readBy = new[] {"cccc"}
                }
            }).Save();

            var result = DB.Queryable<message>()
                           .Where(m => (new[] { "first-convo", "second-convo" }).Contains(m.conversation))
                           .Select(m => new
                           {
                               m.conversation,
                               unreadCount = m.deliveredTo.Count() - m.readBy.Count()
                           })
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```